# Best way to slice a Django queryset without hitting the database more than once

Tags: django

I'm running a query to get the 5 latest `News` items. In my template, I want to display the first item in one location, then the remaining 4 further down the page.

In my template, I do something like this:

```
{% for n in news|slice:":1" %}
    {{ n.headline }}
{% endfor %}

... more HTML ...

{% for n in news|slice:"1:" %}
    {{ n.headline }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I look in the Debug Toolbar, this results in two queries to the database: one with `LIMIT 1` and another with `LIMIT 4 OFFSET 1`, but otherwise the same. I appreciate this is Django's way of intelligently only requesting the stuff you actually use, but in this case it seems a little excessive. What's the best way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: From a programmer's perspective, you're certainly calling a `for` loop twice, and they are both set to a template that calls a query. Could you grab all 5 at once, store it on the client, and display the contents of a cached copy, instead?

Comment: well, that's what I'm trying to do. In the view, I grab all 5, but the queryset only evaluates when I try to slice the first 1. You're right though, the first for loop doesn't really need to be a loop since it's only 1 item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to force the queryset to evaluate itself before the slice. This could be done as simply as calling `len()` on it in your view before passing it off to the context.

The Django docs have a [complete list of everything that causes a queryset to evaluate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). Just do  something from that list and you're good.

Answer (score 11):

Convert to a sequence in the view, then slice the sequence.

```
var = list(somequery[:5])
```

Comment: Do you mean ``var = list(somequery)[:5]``?

Comment: @Riley: No. That retrieves *all* records and then slices the first 5, whereas what I wrote retrieves the first 5 and lets the template slice the first one off.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I think the wording threw me off.